# Cannot run app from Android Studio 2.3.0 to Emulators in Genymotion 2.8.1

Tags: android, genymotion, linux-mint, android-studio-2.3

I am trying to run app from Android Studio 2.3.0 to a Genymotion Emulator, (emulator spec: Nexus 5 API 22 res 1080x1920 px 4 proc, 2GB RAM) but it always failed with this error message:

```
Installation failed with message Failed to install all .
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

image:
[image]

then when I click OK, another error appears in left bottom corner:
[image]

with this error message:

```
03/25 10:10:56: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_0.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_5.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/dep/dependencies.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_1.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_6.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_4.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_3.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_7.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_8.apk /home/dana/AndroidStudioProjects/Samples/CRUD/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_9.apk 
Error while Installing APKs
```

image:
[image]

and another error message from Event Log:

```
10:08 AM    Session 'app': Error Installing APKs

10:10 AM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

10:10 AM    Gradle build finished in 1s 533ms

10:10 AM    Error while uploading slice_0.apk : WARNING: linker: /system/lib/libhoudini.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
                    Success: streamed 60803 bytes
```

image: [image]

My laptop spec is Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit as in this image:[image]

From what I know, this problem is related with adb when apk is sliced to multiple parts by adb.

When I try to run apps to different emulator from same genymotion, I got the same error. emulator spec is Nexus 5 API 23 with 1 proc & 2 GB RAM.

I believe I am not the only one suffer from this problem. I will appreciate any help. Thanks before

Answer (score 2):

add this to your manifest file

```
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: yes, I tried to install into physical device (xiaomi redmi 2) & avd (android studio built-in emulator). all is running well. I only got problem with genymotion 2.8.1

Comment: check the memory allocation and free space of your virtual device

Answer (score 1):

I have receiver error same this. I have try reinstall virtual box and genymotion have working

Comment: i have found this type of error when i am installing application in my android phone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issues.

I solve it by disabling Instant Run in Android Studio: Preferences / Build, Execution, Deployment / Instant Run, first checkbox.

I do not have time to really understand why but in my case it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

- Disabled Instant Run in Android Studio: File - Settings - Build,Execution,Deployment - Instant Run - uncheck Enable Instant Run.
- Emulator: Settings - Security - Turn ON (Unknown Resources - Allow Installations of apps from unknown resources).
- Emulator: Dev Settings - Debugging Section - Turn On(USB Debugging and Verify apps over USB). I highly doubt USB debugging has anything to do with it.